# Steady State Temperature Distribution in a Rectangular Plate

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, heat-equation, steady-state

We need to solve the following :

$$
\nabla^2=0, 0\leq \leq, 0\leq y\leq b
$$
satisfying the boundary conditions
$$
(0,y)=0, 0\leq y\leq b \\
(,0)=(,)=0, 0\leq \leq  \\
_x(a,)=T\sin^3(πy/a)
$$

I proceeded as following:

[Page1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrqIZ.jpg)

[Page2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TZ0W.jpg)

[Page3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBmcV.jpg)

I'm pretty sure my steps till $Y_n(y)$ are correct. Everything beyond that was just a guess and most probably wrong. I doubt if the question itself, which was asked previously in an exam, is correct.

Help me regarding the correctness of either the question or the solution.

Answer (score 4):

if you look at the non trivial boundary, i mean $u_x(a,y)$, you can see it has functionality of $y$ (as in general it should have) while $x'_n(a)$ is just a number! so this assignment
$$
x'_n(a) = \frac{T \sin^3(\pi y/a)}{\sin(n \pi y/b)}
$$
is either completely wrong or just mean the fraction in right hand side is a constant which doesn't seem true! so this is the start of where you should know something is wrong.

---

for solving this problem you should finish construction of $u(x,y)$ completely and then try to use non-trivial boundary condition. so till the point
$$
x_n(x) = c_n \sinh (\frac{n\pi x}{b})
$$
everything is alright. ($c_n$ is still an unknown constant so $2c_n$ or $c_n$ doesn't matter) 
so general representation of $u(x,y)$ would be:
$$
u(x,y) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} A_n u_n(x,y) =\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} A_n x_n(x)y_n(y) \\
= \boxed {\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} A_n \sinh (\frac{n\pi x}{b}) \sin(\frac{n\pi y}{b})}. \tag{1}\label{1}
$$
therefore the problem is finding $A_n$. we also have
$$
u_x(x,y) =  \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} A_n (\frac{n\pi}{b}) \cosh(\frac{n\pi x}{b}) \sin(\frac{n\pi y}{b}) = \frac{\pi}{b}\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} n.A_n  \cosh(\frac{n\pi x}{b}) \sin(\frac{n\pi y}{b}).
$$
Now we should use condition $u_x(a,y)$:
$$
u_x(a,y) = \frac{\pi}{b}\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} n.A_n  \cosh(\frac{n\pi a}{b}) \sin(\frac{n\pi y}{b})  = T \sin^3(\frac{\pi y}{a}) \tag{2}\label{2}
$$
for solving this you should use orthoganality relation of $y_n(y)=\sin(\frac{n\pi y}{b})$ which is :
$$
\int_0^b y_n(y) y_m(y) dy = \frac{b}{2} \delta_{n,m}
$$
where $\delta_{n,m}$ is [kroneker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) . So multiply $\eqref{2}$ by $y_m(y)=\sin(\frac{m\pi y}{b})$ and integrate it from $0$ to $b$ :
$$
\frac{\pi}{b}\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} n.A_n  \cosh(\frac{n\pi a}{b}) (\frac{b}{2} \delta_{n,m}) = T \int_0^b \sin(\frac{m\pi y}{b}) \sin^3(\frac{\pi y}{a}) dy \\
A_m \frac{m \pi}{2} \cosh(\frac{m\pi a}{b}) = T \int_0^b \sin(\frac{m\pi y}{b}) \sin^3(\frac{\pi y}{a}) dy .
$$
Hence
$$
\boxed {A_n = \frac{2T}{n\pi \cosh(\frac{n\pi a}{b}) } \int_0^b \sin(\frac{n\pi y}{b}) \sin^3(\frac{\pi y}{a}) dy}. \tag{3}\label{3}
$$
So $u(x,y)$ is expanding as $\eqref{1}$ with $A_n$ defined as $\eqref{3}$. 
I'm pretty sure the integral $\eqref{3}$ should have explicit form but in case of $a$ be the denominator in $\sin^3$ it should be very complicated.